# How can I generate a random set once in SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, render

I am using SDL and I have created a function that will create a random set of pieces and render them. However, when I run the program it will constantly render a new random set of pieces on a 10 by 10 grid. I would like to know how I can get it so render once and no longer generate a new set, but still be able to edit the locations.

```
void generatelocation(int loc[10][10]){
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        for(int m = 0; m<10; m++){
            loc[n][m] = rand()%6;
        }
    }
    int redcount = 0;
    int orangecount = 0;
    int yellowcount = 0;
    int greencount = 0;
    int bluecount = 0;
    int purplecount = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        for(int m = 0; m<10; m++){
            switch (loc[n][m]){
                case 0:
                    redcount++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    orangecount++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    yellowcount++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    greencount++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    bluecount++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    purplecount++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (redcount < 2 or orangecount < 2 or yellowcount < 1 or greencount < 1 or bluecount < 1 or purplecount < 1){
        generatelocation(loc);
    }
}
void piecerender(){
    int loc[10][10];
    generatelocation(loc);
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++){
        for(int m = 0; m<10; m++){
            switch (loc[n][m]){
                case 0:
                    gRedTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gOrangeTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gYellowTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gGreenTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gBlueTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gPurpleTexture.render(248+48*n, 128+48*m);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function I have for generating the set and I put it in the main loop.

Comment: Just generate them once, instead of before each display call ?

Comment: @Quentin How can I do that? Would I take it out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Create your array "loc" outside of your location generation and render functions. Just now you are creating a new array each time you render (multiple times a second). You can create your array once, and then pass it to your location generation function which can alter the values stored in your array, and then to your render function. This will also reduce the memory use of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but why don't you make a class with a function to generate and another function to edit the locations? Your code for execution would then be:

```
    set.generate();
    set.render();
    set.editLocation();
```

Simply put, is separating the functions an issue?